# How do I set the URL of the page viewer web part through code?

Tags: page-viewer-web-part

I have a requirement to provide the web page URL to the Page Viewer Web Part dynamically (i.e through code).

We cannot extend the Page Viewer Web Part as it is sealed.

Please explain how to do this?

Comment: i got the solution :

PageViewerWebPart oWebPart = new PageViewerWebPart();
oWebPart.ContentLink = "http://www.mindtree.com";
this.Controls.Add(oWebPart);

Answer (score 1):

From comment:

```
PageViewerWebPart oWebPart = new PageViewerWebPart();
oWebPart.ContentLink = "mindtree.com";
this.Controls.Add(oWebPart);
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use the `http://` otherwise it will not work...

```
oWebPart.ContentLink = "http://www.cnn.com";
```